# CURL - cookie not enabled/session expired

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to log into a website using PHP CURL. It all works fine on websites which doesn't require cookies and session but it doesn't seem to work with the websites which rquire you so here is my code I found this code over [here](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/php/examples/ebay_login.html)
any help on this would be apritiated thanks

**Code**

```
<?php
```

// 1-Get First Login Page http://signin.ebay.com/aw-cgi/eBayISAPI.dll?SignIn

```
$ebay_user_id = "username"; // Please set your Ebay ID
$ebay_user_password = "password"; // Please set your Ebay Password
$cookie_file_path = "cookie.txt"; // Please set your Cookie File path

$LOGINURL = "__";
$agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.4) Gecko/20030624 Netscape/7.1 (ax)";
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$LOGINURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
//    curl_close ($ch);

// 2- Post Login Data to Page http://signin.ebay.com/aw-cgi/eBayISAPI.dll

$LOGINURL = "url";
$POSTFIELDS = 'postfiends';
$reffer = "url";

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$LOGINURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$POSTFIELDS); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $reffer);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
//    curl_close ($ch); 
print   $result;    

 ?>
```

Comment: does your cookie.txt contain data after your first cURL process..?

Comment: yes some data gets written to the cookie.txt file

Comment: what error does it actually show..?

Comment: no error it just says you need to enable your cookies or session has expired

Comment: @tushar-chutani try the suggestions in my answer. Sure that helps... Good luck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://signin.ebay.com/aw-cgi/eBayISAPI.dll not only expects username and password as post data, but other parameters as well, maybe you didn't take account of that. Use Net tab on firebug to see the parameters passed, and try to duplicate it.

Comment: Hey, I have made sure I have put in all post parameters I am using httpliveheaders

Comment: @tushar-chutani I have done a lot of work using curl, cookie problems is usual. `In order to help other users of the community (remember that this site is based in common efforts)`, please explain how is that passing all post fields will solve a totally distinct issue that is what you refer in your question: `cookie not enable/session expired`. THX.-

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need more options:

```
// define some HTTP headers 
$headers[] = "Accept: */*";
$headers[] = "Connection: Keep-Alive";
$headers[] = "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";

// to GET add
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,  0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);        

// to POST add
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,  1);

// check for errors before close
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result === false)
{
    echo curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Be sure that your `$cookie_file_path` file is writable (if Linux). Play with `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` and `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER`.

Comment: NomikOS is correct; this answer was hard to find online.  Thanks