# PHP CURL Request Failing When Site Requires Cookies Enabled

Tags: php, html, redirect, cookies, curl

I am trying to grab the meta data from a news article on the NY Times website, specifically http://www.nytimes.com/2014/06/25/us/politics/thad-cochran-chris-mcdaniel-mississippi-senate-primary.html

Whenever I try however I am getting redirects from the sight because my "browser" does not accept cookies.  I have enabled the curl options to save cookies and tried following the accepted answers in a few other StackOverflow questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797510/file-get-contents-receive-cookies), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592270/php-get-html-source-code-with-curl), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468925/curl-cookie-not-enabled-session-expired)) and while the answer worked on those websites it doesn't seem to work on the nytimes site.

My current php curl function looks like this:

```
function get_extra_meta_tags_curl($url) {
    $ckfile = tempnam("/public_html/commentarium/", "cookies.txt");

    $ch = curl_init($main_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    echo $output;
}
```

The problem appears to be that when I request the URL, nytimes.com checks if the browser accepts cookies.  I checks a couple of times before redirecting to the login page with a REFUSE_COOKIE_ERROR.  Instead of posting the full redirect list here you can see it on my test page [here](http://www.commentarium.npctimes.com/php/test_space.php) along with the raw html that the final redirect returns and what my current get_extra_meta_tags_curl function is returning under **CURL test**

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You enable cookies auto-handling in wrong manner. `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` only enables cookies saving (storing), but you need also enable cookies loading and passing them with request (by `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` option). Otherwise cookies auto-handling won't work and you will experienced mentioned "Browser does not accept cookies" problem.

So you have to set both `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` options to the same value (`$ckfile`) at **each** CURL request:

```
...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);
...
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that as was suggested in one of the other stackoverflow questions but I am still getting the same response.  I have updated my question to reflect your suggestion as well as the test page.

Comment: @Russell Winkler Read the answer attentively. You have to set **both** options at **each** CURL request

Comment: I apologize, that was my error in updating the post.  I did add the `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` in both requests and have now updated the post appropriately.